# Spark Streaming Standalone : Save logs

Tags: scala, logging, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am running a spark-streaming application on a standalone setup (version 1.6.1). When I run the application using spark-submit, the logs show up on the terminal. These are useful later on, for instance, to understand what the reason for the failure of the app was, if it failed.

From what I read over the documentation, I have `spark.eventLog.enabled` flag set to true. But, this only saves the event logs to tmp/spark-events folder. These logs are of not much use to me , as I see it. My jobs fail often, due to many exceptions. What is the correct way to store these logs which show up in the terminal (I am guessing, the driver logs?) and analyse my exceptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added these lines to SPARK_HOME/conf/log4j.properties

```
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=/tmp/application.log
log4j.appender.file.append=false
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Any log4j appender can be used. I am using file appender here.

P.S Still, the stdout logs are missing. Only stderr logs are being saved. Yet to figure out why.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to log events that happen on the *driver* side, the easiest way is to provide spark with a logging configuration file. By default, spark uses log4j to do the logging, so when starting your spark-submit job, you can use the `spark.driver.extraJavaOptions` flag to pass in your log4j configuration, and add a `RollingFileAppender` to it:

```
spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=/path/to/your/log4j.xml
```

This is a basic pattern for log4j-1.2 rolling appender xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration>
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <file value="log.txt" />
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <rollingStyle value="Size" />
        <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
        <maximumFileSize value="100KB" />
        <staticLogFileName value="true" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <logger name="log4j.rootLogger" additivity="false">
    <level value="DEBUG"/>
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
</logger>
</log4j:configuration>
```

You can find more information in the [Spark Configuration](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#configuring-logging) section of the spark documentation.

If you want to also log events that happen on the driver nodes, then I suggest you look into an external service which can collection logs from distributed systems.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I haven't had a chance to test this out. Will get back asap

Comment: Hey I just tried this and is getting many log4j:WARN statements with at the end : `'....log4j:ERROR No appender named [FILE] could be found.
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties'`

Comment: @Aswin Fixed it. It should be "RollingFileAppender".

Comment: Thanks, but I am still getting ERROR logs. Any idea why these might be happening? I've added the logs to the Edit section in the question.

Comment: @Aswin For some reason it isn't finding the `RoleFileAppender` class. Perhaps you want to explicitly pass the log4j jar to spark driver via `spark.driver.extraClassPath`

Comment: I tried adding log4j-api-2.5.jar and log4j-core-2.5.jar. No luck, getting same error

Comment: You're using log4j2, which has a different XML format. The one I gave you is for log4j 1.2, I also wrote that in the answer :)

Comment: Okay, I edited the log4j.properties.template file and added a log4j.properties file with File appender. Seems to work. Thanks anyway!